# bash : grep gives "No such file or directory" while searching for text in log

Tags: bash, grep

in bash script i have these relative lines:

```
find_time(){ 
    args=( -A2 'Finished import for test' /var/apps/log/app.log )
     
    while    [ -z "$per_time" ] && [ $COUNTER -lt 3   ] ; do
        if grep -q "${args[@]}" ; then
            per_time=$(grep "${args[@]}" | grep Time) 
            output_time 
        elif ssh user@hostname grep -q -A2 'Finished import for test' /var/apps/log/app.log ; then
            per_time=$(ssh user@hostname 'grep -s -A2 "Finished import for test" /var/apps/log/app.log | grep "Time"') 
            output_time 
        else 
            sleep 60
        fi;  
     COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
    done 
    echo "find_time OK"
}
 
output_time () {
    time=${perf_time//[!0-9]/}
    #convert to seconds and round the value
    time=$(echo $time | sed 's/^\(.\{2\}\)/\1./' | awk '{ printf "%.1f\n",$1}')     
    echo -e "kpi5 : "$time" sec " >> "$result_file"
}

find_time
```

it gives me right result, however it shows in shell:

*grep: import: No such file or directory 

grep: for: No such file or directory

grep: test: No such file or directory*

can not find out how to solve it.

Comment: You have 5 different `grep` commands in your shell script and haven't told us which one(s) produces those error messages. Please create and post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output and code that JUST demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I can see things in your script that http://shellcheck.net would tell you about (e.g. missing quotes in `echo $time`) - please make sure to copy/paste any script you post into shellcheck and fix any issues it tells you about before posting.

Comment: I see at `per_time=$(ssh user@hostname 'grep...` you knew to put quotes around your grep command but at `elif ssh user@hostname grep` you didn't do so - If I were you I'd look into that, assuming you still have a problem after fixing the shellcheck issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the whole command inside single quotes.
So, I think you can try this one:

```
$(ssh user@host 'grep -A2 "Finished import for test " /var/apps/log/app.log | grep "Time"')
```

Comment: thx for reply,  but it gives me same result

Comment: It worked for my test. Pls share rest of code or show how you use `per_time`.

Comment: it works in script as such.  the execution  in shell gives the above outcome ,but still working ..it's just bothering my mind why.  Retrieve value is written to textfile.

Comment: Pls, edit your question and add your code.

Comment: I tried in both ways as well and worked seamlessly for me... copy your code here to check if it has some warnings https://www.shellcheck.net/ .